# how to display corresponding record from access based on other column in Datagrid in vb6

Tags: mysql, ms-access, datagrid, vb6

I am using Vb6 ! I have one datagrid named "Datagrid1" and i display certain contents such as subjectname, subjectcode, theory_practical from the table named "subjectcode" in Datagrid1 from access database.

And i have another table named "feedetail". My doubt is, if the "theory_practical" value is theory means, then it should display the theoryfee from the table named feedetail or if "theroy_practical" value is practical means, then it should display practical fee in the new column named "Fee" in datagrid1.

I am having confusion with the sql statement and displaying in datagrid ! here is my code that i used!

I want to display the corresponding fee in the next column to the Theory_Practical heading ! I can't attach a screenshot file n it shows error! [so here is the link of the screenshot file](http://tinypic.com/r/2gwtdaq/6)!  Thanks in advance !

```
    Public con As New ADODB.Connection
    Public rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    Public rs2 As New ADODB.Recordset

    Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Dim semesternew As String
    semesternew = semester.Caption
    Select Case semesternew
    Case "I"
    semester1 = 1
    Case "II"
    semester1 = 2
    Case "III"
    semester1 = 3
    Case "IV"
    semester1 = 4
    Case "V"
    semester1 = 5
    Case "VI"
    semester1 = 6
    End Select
    DataGrid1.ClearFields
    rs.Open "select Subjectcode,Subjectname,Theory_Practical from subjectcode as s where s.Degree='" & Degree & "' and s.Branch='" & course & "' and s.Year1='" & year1 & "' and s.Year2='" & year2 & "' and s.Semester='" & semester1 & "'  ", con, 1, 3
    Set DataGrid1.DataSource = rs
    End Sub

    Private Sub Command2_Click()
    examfee2.Hide
    examfee1.Show
    End Sub

    Private Sub Command4_Click()
    If rs!Theory_Practical = "theory" Then
    rs2.Open "select Theoryfee from Degreelevel", con, 1, 3
    Set DataGrid2.DataSource = rs2
    ElseIf rs!Theory_Practical = "practical" Then
    rs2.Open "select Practicalfee from Degreelevel", con, 1, 3
    Set DataGrid2.DataSource = rs2
    End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form_Load()
    Set con = New ADODB.Connection
    con.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=.\college.mdb;Persist Security Info=False"
    con.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    End Sub
```

---

Fee table:

```
Heading(Year1,Year2,Theoryfee,Practicalfee) 
values (2001,2003,440,320)
```

All other values like this only with different values !

subjectcode table :

```
Heading(Year1,Year2,Subjectcode,Subjectname,Theory_Practical) 
values (2001,2003,RCCS10CS1,C programming, Theory)
```

Comment: What fields (columns) are in the table `Degreelevel`? You need to be able to join it to the table `subjectcode`.

Comment: The degreelevel table contains columns Theoryfee and Practical fee ! The column name 'Theory_Practical' in subjectcode table contains theory/practical and so the corresponding fee should be displayed in the datagrid !

Comment: Jack, can you create a query that joins on those fields? If you are having problems, you should post sample data. A statement of what you want to do if not so much use.

Comment: Thanks remou for the reply ! Hope you have seen the screenshot of the result that i have posted above ! In the picture, see the datagrid having 3 column named Subjectcode, subjectname, theory_practical. i want another column in the datagrid next to theory_practical which named "FEE" ! There is one table already exists in the database named "feedetail". It contains four column named year1,year2,theoryfee,practicalfee. In datagrid, the new column name FEE should display the certain amount based on the batch for the theory and practical fee ! but i don't know how to use this in sql query !

Comment: Yes, I read your question. Post sample data from both tables. Data, not pictures.

Comment: Fee table: Heading(Year1,Year2,Theoryfee,Practicalfee) values (2001,2003,440,320) All other values  like this only with different values ! subjectcode table : Heading(Year1,Year2,Subjectcode,Subjectname,Theory_Practical) values (2001,2003,RCCS10CS1,C programming, Theory)
My doubt is, In subjectcode table a heading named "Theory_Practical" contains values as "theory" or "practical". If that value is "theory" means, then the theoryfee with corresponding year should be displayed and at the same time, if another data contain "practical" means then practicalfee should be displayed from fee table!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a query like so:

```
SELECT subjectcode.Year1, subjectcode.Year2, 
       subjectcode.Subjectcode, subjectcode.Subjectname, 
       subjectcode.Theory_Practical, q.fee
FROM subjectcode 
INNER JOIN (
       SELECT fees.Year1, fees.Year2, "Theory" As FeeType, 
              fees.Theoryfee As Fee
       FROM fees
       UNION ALL
       SELECT fees.Year1, fees.Year2, "Practical" As FeeType, 
              fees.Practicalfee As Fee
       FROM fees)  AS q 
ON (subjectcode.Theory_Practical = q.FeeType) 
   AND (subjectcode.Year2 = q.Year2) 
   AND (subjectcode.Year1 = q.Year1)
```

However, you would be much better off redesigning your fees table to match the data returned by the inner sql, that is, a different line for theory and practical fees:

```
Year1   Year2   FeeType     Fee
2001    2003    Theory      440
2001    2003    Practical   320
```

Comment: Thank you so much Remou for the reply ! But it shows error "No value has been given for one or more parameters" and it shows error in 6th and 10th in above query in "theory" and "practical". So i just removed double quotes and it showed still error. So i put single quote but it shows still error ! You said i should alter the fee table an could you be more specific on how can i change that table friend because i am new to this ! Again thanks for your valuable time ! :)

Comment: If your data is in MySQL, you could have problems with a union query. Where are you building the query Access or MySQL? Where is the data stored? When I say a single line for each fee, that is exactly what I mean.

Comment: I am using the query in Vb6 to Microsoft Access and data stored in Access only friend !

Comment: If the data is in MS Access and the tables  are the same as you showed, the query should run. It is tested in MS Access. Paste it into MS Access query design window and test. Ensure that the tables are as you said they are.

Comment: Remou thank uuuuuuu soooo much friend ! it really worked :) :) I just made a small mistake in the query while typing and so i just copy pasted ur above query n it really worked ! really happy friend :) I have another doubt and Here is the link of that question friend. [Take a look into that here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14335287/vb6-record-updation-error)