# Vb6 Record Updation Error

Tags: mysql, ms-access, datagrid, vb6

In vb6, a form containing following values and  [here is the screenshot link for the sample values !](http://tinypic.com/r/j0bg4k/6)

And I am using Ms Access 2007 and it contains a table named "studentexamdetail" contains

```
    heading(Admno,Semester,Subjectcode,Regular_Arrear,Fee)
```

And my doubt is when i click "Save" button in above form(see screenshot), then admission number,semester,all the subjectcode, regular_arrear(we can write manually) and Fee should saved in the "studentexamdetail" table but it stores 1st value only when i use this method !

```
    rs2.Open "select * from studentexamdetail", con, 1, 3
    Do Until rs2.EOF
    rs2.AddNew
    rs2!AdmnNo = admno.Caption
    rs2!semester = semester.Caption
    rs2!Subjectcode = rs.Fields("Subjectcode")
    rs2!Regular_Arrear = "Regular"
    rs2!Fee = rs.Fields("Fee")
    rs2.Update
    rs2.MoveNext
    MsgBox "Record Saved!"
    Loop
```

What changes should i made to store all the values and not 1st value only?
What i need is, I shown below :

```
    Admno Semester Subjectcode Regular_Arrear Fee
    1471     V       RMSC1        Regular     440
    1471     V       RMSC3        Regular     440
    1471     V       RMSC2        Regular     320
```

I want to save values in that table as like above only !

Comment: What is this rs.Fields("Subjectcode")
Are you getting any error? So you are able to add only one row in database which will have value 1471 coming from admno.Caption
Am i correct?

Comment: Also why you need to loop? Instead of loop you can use If not rs2.EOF then

Comment: Please refer link on stackoverflow
[How to properly add new records to empty recordset manually][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293933/how-to-properly-add-new-records-to-empty-recordset-manually


Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply AshReva ! Have u seen the screenshot image friend? In that image, there you can see different values but i want output as i mentioned above ! And i tried If not rs2.Eof and it not working friend ! rs.("Subjectcode") is the value of "Subjectcode" fieldname in that image !

Comment: check my previous post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14302832/how-to-display-corresponding-record-from-access-based-on-other-column-in-datagriand i hope it will solve the confusion and check the bottom of the page for the value of recordset "rs"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem by replacing the "rs2.movenext" to "rs.movenext" and you can see the  rs recordset value in the comment above and i just placed another piece of code "rs2.close"

```
   Do Until rs.EOF
   rs3.Open "select * from studentexamdetail", con, 1, 3
   rs3.AddNew
   rs3!AdmnNo = admno.Caption
   rs3!semester = semester.Caption
   rs3!Subjectcode = rs.Fields("Subjectcode")
   rs3!Regular_Arrear = "Regular"
   rs3!Fee = rs.Fields("Fee")
   rs3.Update
   rs3.Close
   rs.MoveNext
   Loop
   MsgBox "Record Saved!"
```

Thanks God !

Answer (score 1):

The code adds a new row to the end of the `rs2` recordset.  Then it calls `.MoveNext`, which positions the recordset at `.EOF`.  So the `Loop` condition is then `True`, which means it doesn't loop.

It seems you have another recordset, `rs`.  Perhaps that is the one you should loop through instead of `rs2`.

Comment: rs.Open "SELECT subjectcode.Year1, subjectcode.Year2, subjectcode.Subjectcode, subjectcode.Subjectname, subjectcode.Theory_Practical, q.Fee FROM subjectcode INNER JOIN ( SELECT fees.Year1, fees.Year2, 'Theory' As FeeType, fees.Theoryfee As Fee FROM fees UNION ALL SELECT fees.Year1, fees.Year2, 'Practical' As FeeType, fees.Practicalfee As Fee FROM fees)  AS q ON (subjectcode.Theory_Practical = q.FeeType) AND (subjectcode.Year2 = q.Year2) AND (subjectcode.Year1 = q.Year1)", con, 1, 3

This is the value of "rs"  recordset and you can see the output for this in screeenshot i've attached above frnd

Comment: check my previous post and i hope it will solve the confusion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14302832/how-to-display-corresponding-record-from-access-based-on-other-column-in-datagri